# Ruby on Rails - In what file do I add the following: require 'forecast_io'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

Thanks for your help,

I believe this is very simple but I can't figure it out. Following the instructions at https://github.com/darkskyapp/forecast-ruby - it tells me to not forget to add require 'forecast_io' - what file do I put this in?

I've run a scaffold to set up a simple lat and lng, following this guide:
https://campushippo.com/lessons/an-easy-way-to-implement-weather-forecasting-in-rails-9d10403 but keep on getting method errors. So I think we are using different versions of Ruby & Rails, and/or I'm placing this code in the wrong file, or wrong place. My question isn't about method errors, but just where to place this.

I'm unsure whether or not to place it in /config/application.rb; create and place the code in /config/forecast_io.rb; or to create and place it in /config/initializers/forecast_io.rb; or if it's supposed to go somewhere else entirely.

I've looked at the api docs, the ruby wrapper read me, and also have read other tutorials (they won't let me post more links, otherwise I would list them) - one is from hackpsu.westarate that is kind of different with using sinatra, went through the Treehouse tutorial on Rails scaffolding, and began their tutorial on creating an API to better understand REST, and have looked at other rails projects to see how they incorporate external API's, so I'm in the thick of it, and am banging my head against the wall because it seems so simple, but I'm not seeing it yet.

Thanks for your help! 
David

Comment: As answer contains in your question, I recommend you to drop that question. `config/initializers/forecast_io.rb` in your second link.

Comment: Are you saying I should change the question? Or that I had the answer in the question?

Comment: The problem with your question is that you don't get how boot process (initializers to be specific) in Rails working and yet you presenting a link in your question, which if you follow it exactly as it states will give you working app. So question makes no sense for me.

Comment: You're right, I don't understand how boot process and initializers work. I've thrown myself in and am trying to learn as fast as possible. 
It helped me to learn that placing a gem in my Gemfile already requires it by default so I don't have to type 'require etc...'
Thanks for the input, and my apologies for the question.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails, placing a gem in your Gemfile already requires the gem by default, unless explicitly stated to ignore.

If you're still bothered about it though, you could add the `require` option to your gem as such:

```
gem 'forecast_io', require: 'forecast_io'
```

Now, for the rest of the configurations mentioned, you can create a file in your initializers and the following:

```
#config/initializers/forecast_io.rb

ForecastIO.configure do |configuration|
  configuration.api_key = 'this-is-your-api-key'
end
```